# Java Concurrency in Practice Lising7.9

Tags: java

all,
my English is poor, but I'll try best to explain my question.

The code as follows :

```
public class timedRun {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService cancelExec = newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public static void timedRun(final Runnable r,
                                long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException {
        class RethrowableTask implements Runnable {
            private volatile Throwable t;

            public void run() {
                try {
                    r.run();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    this.t = t;
                }
            }

            void rethrow() {
                if (t != null)
                    throw launderThrowable(t);
            }
        }

        RethrowableTask task = new RethrowableTask();
        final Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
        taskThread.start();
        cancelExec.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                taskThread.interrupt();
            }
        }, timeout, unit);
        taskThread.join(unit.toMillis(timeout));
        task.rethrow();
    }
}
```

There is a statement in the book : Even if the task doesn't respond to the respond, the timed run method can still return to its caller.

My question is :
  If I call this method as following:

```
timedRun(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true);
    }
}, /* doesn't matter */, /* doesn't matter */);
```

If r does not respond to the interrupt request, the taskThread may not be interrupted in this code.(Am I right?)
  So this program may not have implemented the funtionality of timed run?

Answer (score 0):

Java interruption is cooperative: it relies upon the thing being interrupted checking for the interrupting and handling it appropriately.

If you have a loop like `while (true);`, it does not check or respond to the interruption.

You could try something like:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().interrupted());
```

But this is a "busy wait": it will keep on checking the interrupted flag far more often than it might change.

It is a lot better just to put the thread to sleep indefinitely:

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // Maybe reset the interrupted flag, if appropriate.
}
```

since this doesn't do anything until the thread is *actually* interrupted.